# Unable to connect to DB2 server via db2cmd

Tags: java, db2, jdb

I'm unable to connect to db2 server using db2cmd command

*db2 connect to mydb user myuser using password*

Getting the following message

`SQL8002N  An attempt to connect to a host failed due to a missing DB2 Connect product or invalid license.  SQLSTATE=42968`

But I have successfully connected to this database using jdbc and I can view the structure.

Has anybody experienced such issue?

Comment: did u check ur product lisence

Comment: My local license is fine as I can access another databases. I have issue with this one. The question is why it is allowed to connect using jdbc but not db2cmd. Doesn't jdbc driver use licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to a iSeries o z/390? or just a LUW (Linux, Unix Windows?)

If you are trying to connect to one of the two first, you need a DB2 Connect license, because they use the DRDA architecture, and it uses a special license.

Check the license

```
db2licm -a
```

If you are trying to connect to a LUW, you do not need any DB2 connect license, but probably there is a problem in you cataloged databases. Check the

```
db2 list node diretory
db2 list db directory
```

Is the database a remote server or is it a local connection?

Also, try to attach to the remote instance, in order to check that the node catalog is right

```
db2 attach to remoteInstance
```

Comment: This is remote db running on z/os. I've added license for DB2 Connect Enterprise Edition V9.5 for Windows(R) as you adviced and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need DB2 Connect to serve as a gateway for CLI connections. The JDBC driver does not need the gateway, as it implements the required protocol.